# How to run a file as executable with a different extension?

Tags: windows, file-extension

After taking a look at the listed processes in Window's TaskManager, I've noticed that there are some process that has a different extension other than .exe. I then opened the folder location of one of those processes and their extension is the same as they are shown in TaskManager. So, I was wondering how they do it. I just wanted to learn how its done.

I've tried renaming my application with a different extension and it didn't run.

Why am I seeking answers to this question? For security purposes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  The `.exe` extension is specifically there to mark executable files.

Comment: Seconding @templatetypedef. This is suspicious as hell, LOL.

Comment: What code are you using to run it with?  Is it reporting any errors, and if so which?

Comment: Are you creating Example.exe by compiling c++ file?

Comment: Yeah. But I've seen processes in Windows taskmanager with a different extension other than .exe. So, I was wondering how they do it.

Comment: Why would you want to confuse your users?  If you're trying to hide an executable file, there are far better techniques.  Someone is bound to find your executable.

Comment: Well one reason is because, sometime debuggers expect all process to end with ".exe". So, yes I am trying to defend my application against debuggers and other malicious tools. I've know other functions can help but I was curious about this one technique.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvotes is that the specific question you're asking (how do I run a non-exe?) isn't really the main question you want answered (how do I prevent someone from debugging or tampering with my program?)  You might want to ask that latter question here to see if you can get any input or advice.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I just started Task Manager and I couldn't see anything but .exe files listed.

Answer (score 4):

Indirectly, the command line "start foo.abc" will run an executable renamed from foo.exe.

More directly, edit the registry. In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, create a new Key with the name .abc.
and set the default value to `abcfile`.

Under `abcfile`, make key, name it `Shell`, and under that, create a new key named `open`, and  under that, create another key named `command`.
Now copy the contents from exefile and copy the contents over.
You may want to search for other instances if ".exe" in the registry to find the appropriate contents, as they seem to change from across Windows versions.

This all of course assumes you have administrator access, because you would of course not do this on any system but your own. :)

Answer (score -1):

open up cmd prompt 
type: `start pathOfFile\file.pdf /c vshost.exe`

this will run your file with pdf extension as .exe or any other you wanna give

don't misuse it, think someone helped you out, before harming any one

Comment: What are you talking about in your last paragraph?